# Disable Parent’s ScrollViewer from Child

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a window which has some controls. Among these controls I have a content control, which is being used to open multiple views. This content control resides under a ScrollViewer.  As in below code:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Height="350"
        Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="2"
                      VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" 
                      HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <ContentControl x:Name="ActiveItem" 
                            HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                            VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"/>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

We have different views, which we used to open by setting these as ActiveItem. In one view I want to disable the parent's ScrollViewer. Is there any possible way? (changes can only be done in View’s XAML). Thanks

Comment: Even with a clear View - Code separation you should be allowed to use things like `AttachedProperty` in order to code some View-only concerns.

Answer (score 2):

In XAML? No. XAML is a *markup* language and nothing else.

But you could use the following method to find the parent `ScrollViewer` element in the visual tree:

```
public static T FindParent<T>(DependencyObject dependencyObject) where T : DependencyObject
{
    var parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(dependencyObject);

    if (parent == null) return null;

    var parentT = parent as T;
    return parentT ?? FindParent<T>(parent);
}
```

Usage:

```
ActiveItem.Loaded += (s, e) => 
{
    ScrollViewer sv = FindParent<ScrollViewer>(ActiveItem);
    if (sv != null)
    {
        ...
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a bool property in the view model to indicate which view needs the scroll viewer and bind it to the 'VerticalScrollBarVisibility' with some converter to convert bool to Disabled/Auto.

Somehting like:

```
<ScrollViewer Grid.Row="2"
                      VerticalScrollBarVisibility="{Binding IsScrollNeeded, Converter={StaticResource someConverter}}" 
                      HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <ContentControl x:Name="ActiveItem" 
                            HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                            VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"/>
        </ScrollViewer>
```